# jQuery .ajax PUT request not respecting custom header

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers

I'm losing my custom header when using PUT type with .ajax. But, the header is fine with GET, but gets mangled with PUT. Please see evidence 1:

// GOOD GET:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
    }
});

// Actual header sent (using fiddler):
Accept: application/json
```

// BAD PUT:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json"
    }
});

// Actual header sent (using fiddler):
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

As you can see the only difference is the value of type causing the value of the Accept part of the header gets trashed. jquery-1.8.2.js. Any thoughts? Thanks

Stabby

Comment: From jQuery API docs: `The type of request to make ("POST" or "GET"), default is "GET". Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers.`

Comment: I saw that in their documentation, but I expected either webkit or FF to work with PUTs and they don't. This leads me to believe its a problem with jquery. Doesn't .ajax set the headers. I will test with plain xhr requests today

Comment: I would "expect" those browser to work too, but what do we really know? At the same time, there could be a good chance it's jQuery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it is browser related:

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/WqXzA/

```
Request URL:http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json
```

Chrome 25.0

Comment: I do in fact get different Accept headers in firefox and chrome. Chrome gives me */*. Does this mean that I basically have no control over the accept header when using a PUT? THats a hard pill to swallow